# How do I interpret the integral of the path velocity?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

Assume I have a path or trajectory over time

$$ \boldsymbol{s}(t) = [x_1(t), \dots, x_m(t)] $$

The velocity is

$$ \boldsymbol{v} = \frac{ds}{dt}\boldsymbol{e}_t = v \boldsymbol{e}_t$$ where $\boldsymbol{e}_t$ is a unit vector in the tangent direction. The magnitude of the velocity is

$$ v = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{\left(\frac{dx_i}{dt}\right)^2}} $$

What is the interpretation or physical significance of the integral:

$$ \int{v dt} $$

Comment: Distance travelled? As you wrote, $v = \frac {ds} {dt}$

Comment: @jaslibra that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate velocity as a function of time:
$$ \int{v(t) dt} $$ you are left with your total distance traveled. Because velocity is your change in position as a function of time, integrating velocity as a function of time simply returns your total distance traveled. Similarly, the displacement can be found by evaluating $$ \int{|v(t)| dt} $$

As a general rule, if f(t) represents a change in something, then $\int_a^b{f(t) dt}$ will compute the total change from $t = a$ to $t = b$

Comment: I think you have the terms displacement and distanced interchanged

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between total distance and "scalar quantity of your distance"? The magnitude of the velocity as defined in question is always positive

Comment: I actually had it right in the first place. Distance is a scalar quantity and displacement is a vector quantity. Thus distance is the total ground the object has covered, while displacement is the change from initial to final position.